# casperjs click in radio button doesn't work

Tags: javascript, click, radio-button, casperjs

I know that there are a lot of question about how to click in a radio button with casperjs, and I have read some of then, The problem is that I'm not able to make it works.

This is part of a form, here is the html code with the radio buttons:

```html
<ul>

    <li>
      <input id="gender1" name="gender" value="10" onclick="groupFilledField(this);" type="radio">
      <label for="gender1" class="radio">Hombre</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input id="gender2" name="gender" value="20" onclick="groupFilledField(this);" type="radio">
      <label for="gender2" class="radio">Mujer</label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And here is my code casperjs code:

```js
casper.then(function() {
  this.click('input[id="gender1"][value="10"]');

});

casper.fill('form[action="/candidate/create-profile/personal-data-run.xhtml"]', config.form2, true);
casper.waitForSelector("#save").thenClick("#save");

casper.wait(5000).then(function() {
  this.capture('testlol.png');
});
```

Any suggestion what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: This has probably nothing to do with the radio button. Your `casper.fill` is misplaced. `casper.fill` is executed immediately when called, but `casper.then` and `casper.waitForSelector` create steps in the queue. Wrap `casper.fill` in `casper.then` and see if it helps.

Comment: Thanks Artjom. I dit it, but the problem is the onclick="groupFilledField(this) function. It doesn't run with casperjs.

Comment: Which PhantomJS version do you use? Please register to the `resource.error`, `page.error`, `remote.message` and `casper.page.onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf#file-2_caspererrors-js)). Maybe there are errors. There is a known issue in PhantomJS 2.x, where some errors are not shown. You may try to use 1.9.7 or 1.9.8 in that case.